# How to workaround the inconsistent definition of numeric_limits<T>::min()?

Tags: c++, standard-library

The numeric_limits traits is supposed to be a general way of obtaining various type infomation, to be able to do things like

```
template<typename T>
T min(const std::vector<T>& vect)
{
    T val = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();

    for(int i=0 ; i<vect.size() ; i++)
        val = max(T, vect[i]);

    return val;
}
```

The problem is that (at least using MS Visual Studio 2008) numeric_limits<int>::min() returns the smallest negative number, while numeric_limits<double>::min() returns the smallest *positive* number!

Anyone knows the rationalie behind this design? Is there a better (recommended?) way of using numeric_limits? In my specific function above, I could of course initialize T to vect[0], but that is not the answer I am looking for..

See also (floating-point-specific) discussion
[here](http://lists.kde.org/?l=kde-devel&m=114621233629277&w=2)

Comment: There are two bugs in your example.

1. The function should be called max(), since it calculates the maximum element.

2. the line "val = max(T, vect[i])" should be "val = max(val, vect[i])".

Answer (score 9):

You can use Boost libraries. The library Numeric Conversions provides a class called bounds that can be used consistently.

See the documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/bounds___traits_class.html).

Answer (score 6):

This is an old thread, but there is an updated answer:

C++11 added a `lowest()` function to `std::numeric_limits` ([See here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/))

So you can now call `std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest()` to get the lowest representable negative value.

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of min() isn't all that strange, it returns `FLT_MIN`, `DBL_MIN` or `INT_MIN` (or their respective values), depending on the type you specialize with. So your question should be why `FLT_MIN` and `DBL_MIN` are defined differently from `INT_MIN`.

Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to that latter question.

My suspicion is that it was defined that way for practical purposes. For integer numbers, you're usually concerned with overflow/underflow, where the minimum and maximum value become of interest.

For floating point numbers, there exists a different kind of underflow in that a calculation could result in a value that's larger than zero, but smaller than the smallest representable decimal for that floating point type. Knowing that smallest representable floating point value allows you to work around the issue. See also the Wikipedia article on [subnormal/denormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal) numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be

```
double val = -std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
```

Of course, this doesn't explain the strange behaviour of numerics_limits::min() which could be a result of the fact that there are different min/max borders for integers (min = -2^n, max = 2^n-1) but not for doubles.

Comment: Is std::numeric_limits<int>::max() == -std::numeric_limits<int>::min() ?

Comment: I don't think so - as I wrote, I think that min = -2^31, max = 2^31-1 for 32-bit datatypes for example. This represents the greatest negative/positive int value - gcc confirms this: "min: -2147483648, max: 2147483647"

Comment: No, my code is for double, not for int. For the double type, the behaviour is different (min gives the smallest positive double value) -  that's the point of the OP's question. So the workaround to get the greatest negative value (expected min behaviour) would be that code. Of course, that won't work for all types or templates, just for the special double type case.

Comment: Boost bounds (1.38) says aboute `lowest`: "Returns the minimum finite value, equivalent to numeric_limits<T>::min() when T is an integral type, and to -numeric_limits<T>::max() when T is a floating point type." http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/bounds___traits_class.html

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the smallest value for an empty vector can be argued. If the vector is empty then there is no smallest element.

Prefer to use [std::min_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) instead:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 1000, std::rand);

    std::vector<int>::iterator it  = std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    if (it == v.end())
    {
        std::cout << "There is no smallest element" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The smallest element is " << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the rationale but it is expected behaviour.  Well, in the sense that is how Josuttis (and, presumably the standard) describes it!

> min(): "Miniumum finite value (minimum
>   normalized value for floating-point
>   types with denormalization)."

As best I can tell if the type is *not* an integer (`numeric_limits<>::is_integer`) and *has* denormalization (`numeric_limits<>::has_denorm`) `min()` will return the smallest representable value by that type.  Otherwise it will return the smallest *value* - which may be negative.

For a more consistent interface check out the [Boost numeric/conversion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/index.html) library.  Specifically the [`bounds` traits class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/bounds___traits_class.html).  Here's a snippet:

```
cout << "lowest float:" << boost::numeric::bounds<float>::lowest();
cout << "lowest int:  " << boost::numeric::bounds<int>::lowest();
```

You may also find the [boost::integer library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/integer/index.html) useful.  It brings some of C99's integer support (like `int_least16_t`) to C++ and can help select the best sized type for you particular need.  An example:

```
boost::uint_t<20>::fast fastest20bits; // fastest unsigned integer that 
                                       // can hold at least 20 bits.
boost::int_max_value_t<100000>::least  // smallest integer that can store
                                       // the value 100000.
```

I often find that when I need one of boost::numeric/conversion or boost::integer I need them both.

Answer (score 1):

`numeric_limits<int>::min` returned the **lowest** negative number, all floating point number types, return the **smallest** positive number when I tried it with Sun CC & g++.

I guess this is because 'smallest' and 'minimum' mean different things with floating point numbers.  It is a bit odd though.

Both Sun CC and g++ produce the same result :

> short:min: -32768 max: 32767
>
> int:min: -2147483648 max: 2147483647
>
> unsigned int:min: 0 max: 4294967295
>
> long:min: -2147483648 max: 2147483647
>
> float:min: 1.17549e-38 max:
>   3.40282e+38
>
> double:min: 2.22507e-308 max:
>   1.79769e+308
>
> long double:min: 3.3621e-4932 max:
>   1.18973e+4932
>
> unsigned short:min: 0 max: 65535
>
> unsigned int:min: 0 max: 4294967295
>
> unsigned long:min: 0 max: 429496729

```
template<typename T>
void showMinMax()
{
    cout << "min: " << numeric_limits<T>::min() << endl;
    cout << "max: " << numeric_limits<T>::max() << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
cout << "short:";
showMinMax<short>()
...etc...etc..
```

Comment: Strange, numeric_limits<double>::min returns a very small positive number here (g++ 3.4.5). Perhaps it depends on the version/OS/implementation