# Issue with std::numeric_limits<T>::min() with float/double values

Tags: c++, c++11

While writing some code to ensure user input is valid I came across an issue with  `std::numeric_limits<T>::min();` where T is a floating point type i.e double/float etc.

Using `-std::numeric_limits<double>::max();` allows me to get the real minimum value but you would expect `std::numeric_limits<double>::min();` to return that.

Why does `std::numeric_limits<double>::min();` not return the smallest possible value of these types and instead force us to use `std::numeric_limits::lowest` or `-std::numeric_limits<double>::max();`?

Comment: You're comparing a number against the minimum of that type to see if it's less than that. That doesn't make sense because if it's less than the minimum, the minimum must be that number and then it's no longer less than the minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using `-max()` will give lowest value.

In C++11 there is also `std::numeric_limits::lowest` that is consistent for reals and ints.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest

See also [How to workaround the inconsistent definition of numeric_limits<T>::min()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801313/how-to-workaround-the-inconsistent-definition-of-numeric-limitstmin)

Comment: Thanks, I gathered as much. Im still interested to know why ::min in this case doesnt return what you would expect however. Any idea?

Comment: I don't know the exact rationale, but C++ follows what FLT_MIN is set to.  I guess it is a matter of minimum floating being an infinity and not a particular finite number.

Comment: I guess that makes some sense but it seems slightly misleading with using the term min I guess.

Comment: I know.  Got bitten by the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this?

This is because  `std::numeric_limits<>::min()` returns implementation defined `FLT_MIN`, `DBL_MIN` or `INT_MIN`. In this regard behavior of this method is consistent. But the return value of`std::numeric_limits<double>::min()`: `DBL_MIN` has slightly different meaning than `INT_MIN`. This is the smallest value that `double` can represent. There might be value greater than 0 but double can't represent it.

> why does using min() not do the same thing in this instance?

The rationale behind this is that you can query `<limits>` for this value to check for this possible underflow specific to floating point arithmetic.

---

You can use

```
std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest()
```

to query for a lowest negative value.